# Pulling values from database in Symfony 2.3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 2.3

I have a function that lets me send email notifications when pressed. It sends email and everything, but when I want to retrieve an id from the database to send it as part of the subject of the email, it doesn't work.

```
private function updateForm($data)
    {
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainBundle:Unity');     
            $attached = $repository->find('unityid');

$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject($attached)
                ->setFrom('some@email')
                ->setTo('some@email')
                ->setBody($attached);
                $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
return true;
}
```

I do not know why I cannot retrieve the ID. I'm doing exactly like the Symfony documentation says.

What am I missing?

Comment: what you doing with that id ?  printing or returning that id ? return true!

Comment: I'm just sending it to the email in ->setBody

Comment: The repository `find()` method finds an entity by its primary key / identifier. `'unityid'` looks like it's probably a column name rather than a primary key value.

Comment: Yes, it is a column name. How would I go to get a value from an specific column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get `Id` from `Unity` entity based on `unityid`. To fine records based on specific column you can use `findOneBy()` or `findBy()`. Here we are using `findOneBy()` doctrine function to get single. Make sure you have replaced `<Your value>` with your value.

```
$attached = $repository->findOneBy(array('unityid' => '<Your value>'));
```

You have not mentioned your primary key of `Unity` entity so we are assuming `id` is name of primary key column. `$attached` is object rather than value so  you need to use `getId()` function to get value of `id` column.

**Full Code**

```
<?php
    private function updateForm($data)
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainBundle:Unity');     
        $attached = $repository->findOnyBy(array('unityid' => '<Your value>'));

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject($attached->getId()) // $attached->getId() returns value of "id" column
            ->setFrom('some@email')
            ->setTo('some@email')
            ->setBody($attached);
            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!